# How can I reshape the tensor

Tags: python

```
tensor([[17,  0],
        [93,  0],
        [ 4,  0],
        [72,  0],
        [83,  0],
        [67,  0],
        [34,  0],
        [21,  0],
        [19,  0])
```

I want to remove 0 from this tensor, which is a two-dimensional array, and make it a one-dimensional array.

How can I make this tensor with the tensor below?

```
tensor([[17],
        [93],
        [4],
        [72],
        [83],
        [67],
        [34],
        [21],
        [19])
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In **Tensorflow**, you can simply use a `boolean_mask`:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

tensor = tf.constant([[17,  0],
        [93,  0],
        [ 4,  0],
        [72,  0],
        [83,  0],
        [67,  0],
        [34,  0],
        [21,  0],
        [19,  0]])
tensor = tf.boolean_mask(tensor, tf.cast(tensor, dtype=tf.bool), axis=0)
```

```
tf.Tensor([17 93  4 72 83 67 34 21 19], shape=(9,), dtype=int32)
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the tensor is a `numpy` array.

Firsly, flatten the matrix using `x= x.flatten()`

Then remove all occurences of `zeros` using `x = x[x!=0]`

Then reshape the array back in 2D using `x = np.reshape(x, ( -1, x.shape[0] ))`

This (`x`) would return you:

```
array([[17, 93,  4, 72, 83, 67, 34, 21, 19]])
```

Comment: However, if the tensor contains [0,0], there is a problem that [0,0] itself disappears. In this case, what should I do?
 
for example, 
tensor([[17,  0],
        [93,  0],
        [ 0,  0],
        [72,  0])


tensor([[17, 93, 72])